# Custom wp_query for related posts with cmb2

Tags: wp-query

Hi there my first time here!
Im using CMB2 to attach posts to an post and i want to make a custom query with the values that cmb2 give me. I try this piece of code, but nothing appears. Can someone help me? I tried with a foreach loop and works, but on the debug bar i get a warning saying that im trying to get a property of a non object.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'amob_rec_posts' ) ) {
      function amob_rec_posts() {
        global $post;
        $rec_posts = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_amobrec_cmb2_post_search_ajax_demo_multiple', true );
        $args = array(
          'post__in' => $rec_posts,
          'ignore_sticky_posts' => 'true'
        );
        $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
        // The Loop
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
          <article class="card">
            <header class="card-header">
              <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                  <figure class="card-thumbnail">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    <span class="icon-rounded"><i class="fa fa-link" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                  </figure>
                </a>
              <?php } ?>
            </header><!-- card header ends -->
            <section class="card-content">
              <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>
              <hr>
              <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </section><!-- card content ends -->
          </article><!-- article ends -->
        </div><!-- card wrapper ends -->
        <?php endwhile;
        endif;
        // Reset Post Data
      wp_reset_postdata();
      }
    }
```